# Using EXIFTool to create sRGB images?

Tags: colors, exif, icc, srgb, exiftool

I would like to ask a question about sRGB, ICC profiles, and exiftool.

I've found that you can use exiftool to embed sRGB profiles into images. Does this mean I can create a picture in Paint.NET and use exiftool to embed an sRGB ICC profile in it... and the output file will be sRGB? As in, color managed across MACs and PCs?

I can't afford photoshop, and am not really crazy about Gimp, so I thought exiftool-ing a profile into a picture could be a quick fix.

I don't know whether this will work (as Paint.NET does not have an option for sRGB), but I hope someone can verify that it has the same effect as saving an image in sRGB in photoshop (and embedding a profile).

Answer (score 0):

Exiv2 or ImageMagick are probably better options. The latter downloads and installs with a small set of commonly-used ICC profiles. You can apply (embed?) them in your images with a simple command in IM as well. The ExifTool command for doing the same is a bit more involved, and doesn't work as well across platforms. Andreas Huggel's Exiv2 can also apply sRGB as an EXIF color mode (mode 1).

And just FYI: MAC is an acronym (Media Access Controller, part of a router or DSL or Cable modem), while Mac is a computer "manufactured" by Apple Computer, Inc. The late Steve Jobs was an odd duck, but one can still show respect to his memory by dropping caps on the A and the C of his "creation." (And this is mild correction compared to how I've seen it on some forums and help sites.)

BZT